# EnvironmentError: No tool named 'fastcpp': not a Zip file:

Tags: python, scons

I am compiling some proprietary code and trying to build an image. Here I am getting an error of

```
EnvironmentError: No tool named 'fastcpp': not a Zip file:
  File ".../build/ms/target.scons", line 145:
    env.Tool('ComSConstruct', toolpath = ['${BUILD_ROOT}/tools/build/scons/build'])
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Environment.py", line 1786:
    tool(self)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Tool/__init__.py", line 191:
    self.generate(env, *args, **kw)
  File ".../tools/build/scons/build/ComSConstruct.py", line 54:
    env.LoadImageUnits(env.get('IMAGE_ROOT_DIR_PATTERNS'))
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Environment.py", line 223:
    return self.method(*nargs, **kwargs)
  File ".../tools/build/scons/scripts/utils.py", line 1286:
    load_sub_scripts(env, dir_patterns, script_name_patterns, "image", clone_env=True)
  File ".../tools/build/scons/scripts/utils.py", line 1540:
    node.load_scripts(script_list, script_type, clone_env=clone_env)
  File ".../tools/build/scons/scripts/utils.py", line 1585:
    env.SConscript(script, exports='env')
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 546:
    return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 260:
    exec _file_ in call_stack[-1].globals
  File ".../bsp/devcfg/build/SConscript", line 312:
    SetupDevCfgBuild(devcfg_env, aliases, 'devcfg')
  File ".../bsp/devcfg/build/SConscript", line 103:
    env.LoadToolScript('llvm', toolpath = ['${BUILD_SCRIPTS_ROOT}'])
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Environment.py", line 223:
    return self.method(*nargs, **kwargs)
  File ".../tools/build/scons/scripts/utils.py", line 1268:
    m.generate(env)
  File ".../tools/build/scons/scripts/llvm.py", line 849:
    env.Tool('fastcpp')
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Environment.py", line 1785:
    tool = SCons.Tool.Tool(tool, toolpath, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Tool/__init__.py", line 105:
    module = self._tool_module()
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Tool/__init__.py", line 165:
    raise SCons.Errors.EnvironmentError(m)
```

I downloaded the [fastcpp](http://fastcpp.com/) from here but not able to understand how can I install it as it has some code files having .hpp extensions.

I have already install scons successfully.

Can anyone explain what is fastcpp and how to use it to fix above error?

## UPDATE: 19/08/2020

It has `ComSConstruct.py` module located at `'${BUILD_ROOT}/tools/build/scons/build'` still it is giving above errors.

I replaced this above path with the path where FastCpp files are present. Now the error is changed to `ComSConstruct` tool.

```
EnvironmentError: No tool named 'ComSConstruct': not a Zip file:
  File ".../build/ms/target.scons", line 146:
    env.Tool('ComSConstruct', toolpath = ['/home/tk/tools_used/FastCpp'])
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Environment.py", line 1785:
    tool = SCons.Tool.Tool(tool, toolpath, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Tool/__init__.py", line 105:
    module = self._tool_module()
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Tool/__init__.py", line 165:
    raise SCons.Errors.EnvironmentError(m)
```

Comment: .hpp is header files for C++, so there's some implication you may need to compile the tool before using it.  Can you provde a bit more information?  e.g. what is the call which leads to the EnvironmentError? Where did you put fastcpp?  What *is* fastcpp, for those of us who don't know?

Comment: Where did you download a SCons fastcpp tool from? The link you have above doesn't work?

Comment: Updated the link. I downloaded the zip file from there. @bdbaddog

Comment: @MatsWichmann updated full error above. fastcpp files are located at `/home/tk/tools_used/FastCpp`.

Comment: Can't really tell much more from this.  The "not a Zip file" comes from Python, when you ask to import something it tries getting it from a zipfile if other methods failed; all that means is that the effort to import fastcpp failed. We still don't know what fastcpp is (the one-pager website only hints), nor how you're trying to use it.

Comment: I try to give zip file of FastCpp folder, but then it gives TypeError, Savage! 
FastCpp doesn't have any bin file or .sh file. It has some .hpp files and I just given a path of a FastCpp folder.

Comment: So fastcpp is NOT a scons tool/builder? If not then env.Tool('fastcpp') of course will fail. If you have a tool/builder you can share that's what we'd need to see. It looks like a software package you link/include files from?

Comment: Just terminology so we're talking about same thing: a "tool" in scons is a Python module that sets up your environment to enable whatever is the subject of the tool, so for example the "gcc" tools sets up using the gcc command to compile C/C++ sources. The Tool() mechanism doesn't just arbitratily allow including an external command or bits of code, if that's what you are trying to do.

Comment: Try to change the some paths and the result is in updated above. 
Just no of errors reduced. But now it started to give actual error ```ComSConstruct``` .

Comment: So to repeat/restate... a tool module is the thing you request when you call `env.Tool('foo')` or `Environment(tools=['foo'])`. SCons searches for a suitable `foo.py` in known places first, your last snip you're not getting *that* failure. Then it tries to import it with Python's import mechanism, and that's where you get the Zip error (because zipimport is the last try in that import sequence).  So the thing you've provided can't be imported.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the solution.

There were some fixes in the proprietary code. I got the patches and applied them manually.

Then, updated the clang 3.4 to clang 4.0 by following below commands. (Failed to install higher clang versions. I think, probably 14.0 is not supporting higher versions.)

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-4.0 main"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clang-4.0 lldb-4.0
```

Compiled again and it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete scons in your Linux.
That scripts use local scons environment.

in error codes:

-> `/usr/lib/scons` : you have a scons lib by apt-get install scons maybe

-> if you autoremove scons and then
That script run in local scons environment in `../build/ms` (it might Q codes)